# Calculator not doing BODMAS correctly

Tags: java, math

I have a assignment where I need to write a calculator that follows the laws of BODMAS. I have written the code for the calculator but it doesn't properly go through the BODMAS rules. This is my code: 
public class Calculator {

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Calculator {

    String expression;
    public Calculator(String expr) {
        this.expression = expr.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
    }

    public double evalExpr() {
        return eval(expression);
    }

    private double eval(String input) {
        if (input.contains("-")) {
            String[] operands = input.split("\\-", 2);
            return eval(operands[0]) - eval(operands[1]);
        } else if (input.contains("+")) {
            String[] operands = input.split("\\+", 2);
            return eval(operands[0]) + eval(operands[1]);
        } else if (input.contains("*")) {
            String[] operands = input.split("\\*", 2);
            return eval(operands[0]) * eval(operands[1]);
        } else if (input.contains("/")){
            String[] operands = input.split("\\/", 2);
            return eval(operands[0]) / eval(operands[1]);
        } else if (input.matches("[0-9]*")) {
            return Integer.parseInt(input);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }

}




public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "6*8/7+6-9+5/4*3-8+6";
        Calculator calc = new Calculator(input);
        double answer = calc.evalExpr();
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

But this version for some reason does not go through the BODMAS. The calculator should return ~ 5.61 for a answer but instead returns 14.10. I cant figure out why as I assumed Java automatically does BODMAS for you. Can anyone figure out what is going wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: so you expect java to know that you happened to want to make a calculator, from strings?, it can't read your mind sadly

Comment: @dave Can you offer any actual help or only sarky, needless comments?

Comment: it looks like if you re-order your if-else-if's in eval, you get different results, though I'm not sure yet what the ordering should be.
@dave did you even read the code? It compiles and runs.

Comment: I know it compiles they were saying why did java not get the rght answer, not why was it not working, all I was saying the reason was that it was what they created not java

Comment: @dave thanks for clarifying the entire purpose SO exists.

Comment: so what is your point? a reorder would get a different aswer but they will also have to do bracket checking etc or you could build a javacc compiler if you really wanted to

Comment: For instance: your expression ends with "8+6". This is evaluated to 14 and substracted from the rest. This of course is not correct. It should substract 8 and after that, add 6. It's evaluating in the wrong order. I'll try to find a solutation and I'll be back

Comment: You can't made a BODMAS compatible calculator with such trivial code.  You'll need a full parser of some sort, e.g. LALR.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your expression contains more '+' and '-'.
In that case, the operands should be evaluated from left to right.

You might try this:

```
private double eval(String input) {
  if (input.contains("-") || input.contains("+"))
  {
    // Get all operands
    String[] operands;
    operands = input.split("[\\+\\-]");

    // Evaluate them from left to right
    int    counter;
    int    index_operator;
    char   operator;
    String operand;
    double result;
    operand = operands[0];
    result = eval(operand);
    index_operator = operand.length();
    for (counter = 1; counter < operands.length; counter++)
    {
      operator = input.charAt(index_operator);
      operand = operands[counter];
      if (operator == '+')
        result += eval(operand);
      else
        result -= eval(operand);
      index_operator += operand.length() + 1;
    }
    return (result);
  } else if (input.contains("*")) {
      String[] operands = input.split("\\*", 2);
      return eval(operands[0]) * eval(operands[1]);
  } else if (input.contains("/")){
      String[] operands = input.split("\\/", 2);
      return eval(operands[0]) / eval(operands[1]);
  } else if (input.matches("[0-9]*")) {
      return Integer.parseInt(input);
  } else {
      throw new RuntimeException();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I more or less rewrote your `Calculator` in order to make it evaluate all additions and substractions from left to right.
Might be helpful.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Calculator
{
  String expression;

  public Calculator(String expr)
  {
    expression = expr.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
  }

  class Operation
  {
    public char   operator;
    public String operand;
  }

  public double evalExpr()
  {
    // -----------------
    // Initialize result
    // -----------------
    double result;
    result = 0;

    // -------------------------------
    // Split expression into its parts
    // -------------------------------
    List<Operation> operations;
    operations = splitExpression(expression);

    // -------------------
    // Evaluate operations
    // -------------------
    Iterator<Operation> it;
    Operation           operation;
    it = operations.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
      operation = it.next();
      switch (operation.operator)
      {
        case '+':
          result += eval(operation.operand);
          break;
        case '-':
          result -= eval(operation.operand);
          break;
        default: // This is the first element in the list
          result = eval(operation.operand);
          break;
      }
    }

    // ----
    // Done
    // ----
    return (result);

  } // evalExpr

  /**
   * This method splits the specified expression.
   * The result is a list of operators and operands.
   * <br>The first element will have an empty operator.
   **/
  private List<Operation> splitExpression(String expression)
  {
    // -----------------
    // Initialize result
    // -----------------
    List<Operation> result;
    result = new ArrayList<Operation>();

    // -------------------------------
    // Split expression into its parts
    // -------------------------------
    String[] parts;
    parts = expression.split("[\\+\\-]");

    // ----------------------------
    // Convert into internal format
    // ----------------------------
    int           counter;
    int           index_operator;
    Operation part;
    index_operator = 0;
    for (counter = 0; counter < parts.length; counter++)
    {
      // ----------------------------
      // Extract operand and operator
      // ----------------------------
      part = new Operation();
      part.operand = parts[counter];
      if (counter == 0)
        part.operator = '\0';
      else
      {
        part.operator = expression.charAt(index_operator);
        index_operator++;
      }

      // ------------------
      // We got another one
      // ------------------
      result.add(part);

      // ----------------------
      // Point to next operator
      // ----------------------
      index_operator += part.operand.length();

    } // for all parts

    // ----
    // Done
    // ----
    return (result);

  } // splitExpression

  private double eval(String input)
  {
    if (input.contains("*"))
    {
      String[] operands = input.split("\\*", 2);
      return eval(operands[0]) * eval(operands[1]);
    }
    else if (input.contains("/"))
    {
      String[] operands = input.split("\\/", 2);
      return eval(operands[0]) / eval(operands[1]);
    }
    else if (input.matches("[0-9]*"))
      return Integer.parseInt(input);
    else
      throw new RuntimeException();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String input = "6*8/7+6-9+5/4*3-8+6";
    Calculator calc = new Calculator(input);
    System.out.println(input);
    double answer = calc.evalExpr();
    System.out.println(answer);
  }

} // class Calculator
```